# Array typedef pointer decomposition in function parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, typedef, reinterpret-cast

I have a simple array typedef

```
typedef char myString[8];
```

And one function that takes a `myString` and another that takes a `myString*`. Interestingly, both of these functions have the exact same implementation and produce the exact same output:

```
void foo(myString s){
    std::string stdstr(reinterpret_cast<char*>(s), 8);
    std::cout << stdstr << std::endl;
}

void bar(myString* s){
    std::string stdstr(reinterpret_cast<char*>(s), 8);
    std::cout << stdstr << std::endl;
}
```

`foo` makes sense to me, but I do not understand what is happening in `bar`. Why is it valid to cast a `myString*` to `char*` in? Isn't the underlying type `char**`? My guess is there is some syntactic sugar at play, but I can't find any references to this particular case.

Note that changing the functions to `void foo(char* s)` and `void bar(char** s)` produces different outputs, as expected.

Working example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/n4dfW5PGj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You introduced the alias `myString` for an array type

```
typedef char myString[8];
```

So this function declaration

```
void bar(myString* s){
```

is equivalent to the declaration

```
void bar( char ( *s )[8] ){
```

If you have an array declared for example like

```
char str[8] = "1234567";
```

and are calling the function `bar` like

```
bar( &str );
```

then the value of the expression `&str` is the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array `str`. That is it is the address of the first element of the array `str` though the type of the expression is `char( * )[8]` instead of `char *`. That is the addresses of  expressions `&str`,  `str` and `&str[0]` are the same.

So within the function this value of the address (the address of the first element of the passed character array) is interpreted as having the type `char *`.

```
std::string stdstr(reinterpret_cast<char*>(s), 8);
```

and you gets the address of the first element of the array of the type `char *`.

Of course you could just write instead

```
std::string stdstr( *s, 8);
```